# usb device descriptor read errors after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: usb, 20.04, log

Since I upgraded to 20.04 I now get a bunch of errors on boot:

`May 13 21:13:24 the-wee-beast kernel: usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71`

Does anyone know what these mean (or can just link me to a resource that explains the error numbers?)

Addendum:

I understand that it is telling me there is an error with a usb device plugged into a particular port, what I would like to know is what read/64 refers to and what an error -71 is (or where the error numbers are listed)

Answer (score -1):

In the interest of being quick, the kernel is telling you there's an issue with your usb hardware: specifically 1-3. Use `lsusb` for figure out which piece of hardware it corresponds to, and make sure that piece of hardware works. Unless you want to fix the issue in question, the number probably isn't that important.

If you're booting is slow, you might consider looking on the web for a workaround, but that may prove iffy. I've had issues in my own usb system since kernel 4.4 and they still haven't been fixed. They are a nuissance but don't keep the computer from not working.

Comment: Sorry should have clarified, I am aware it is telling me there is an error with a usb device plugged into a specific port, what I don't know is what read/64 refers to and what an error -71 is

Comment: I agree with @starvagrant, this is very annoying... And, I will add... that Ubuntu preventing me from using my USB drives is much more than annoying and, no, I cannot use it without that support.