# Slow startup: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command

Tags: boot, usb, kernel

I am facing slow startups here on a fresh 18.04.4 LTS installation. This slow startup seems to be caused by the USB kernel infrastructure hitting some timeout while trying to initialize.

I have unplugged all external USB devices trying to isolate the culprit, but had no luck. The only thing left is the internal flirc module, which is also attached to the USB bus, so this is very unlikely as it was working on Xenial before...

Unfortunately I don't know how to properly interpret the dmesg output. Can someone please tell which device exactly causes the trouble? For example wow should I read this line `usb 3-11: device descriptor read/64, error -110`?

```
$ dmesg
[...]
[   18.840539] usb 3-11: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   34.456541] usb 3-11: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   34.720461] usb 3-11: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[   50.328537] usb 3-11: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   65.944535] usb 3-11: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   66.080494] usb usb3-port11: attempt power cycle
[   66.760460] usb 3-11: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   71.960551] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[   72.196598] usb 3-11: Device not responding to setup address.
[   72.432460] usb 3-11: device not accepting address 5, error -71
[   72.588460] usb 3-11: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[   77.848555] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[   78.084597] usb 3-11: Device not responding to setup address.
[   78.320457] usb 3-11: device not accepting address 6, error -71
[   78.350687] usb usb3-port11: unable to enumerate USB device
[   78.383974] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[   78.423149] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[   78.453215] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[   78.484704] input: flirc.tv flirc Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6:1.0/0003:20A0:0001.0001/input/input3
[   78.572642] input: flirc.tv flirc Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6:1.0/0003:20A0:0001.0001/input/input4
[   78.604675] input: flirc.tv flirc System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6:1.0/0003:20A0:0001.0001/input/input5
[   78.636707] hid-generic 0003:20A0:0001.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.01 Keyboard [flirc.tv flirc] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6/input0
[...]

$ hwinfo 
36: USB 00.1: 0000 Unclassified device
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: zGic.dZ7C1EsCH66
  Parent ID: uIhY.2DFUsyrieMD
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6:1.1
  SysFS BusID: 3-6:1.1
  Hardware Class: unknown
  Model: "Clay Logic flirc"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x20a0 "Clay Logic"
  Device: usb 0x0001 "flirc"
  Revision: "1.00"
  Speed: 1.5 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v20A0p0001d0100dc00dsc00dp00icFFiscFFipFFin01"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #35 (Hub)
  
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp.
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 20a0:0001 Clay Logic
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

**Edit**
After opening up my HTPCs case and unplugging the flirc module it boots just fine and quick without any kernel erros. So this USB device is causing the trouble. However I still dont understand why this out of the sudden started and never was an issue with Xenial. I still would be happy if someone could shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the descriptions [here](https://docs.kernel.org/driver-api/usb/error-codes.html), USB errors use the same old regular errno values we are used to, of which 110 indicates a timeout (ETIMEDOUT)

Answer (score -1):

this should help: https://askubuntu.com/a/1239249/326048

The answer this person gives is a educational answer about diagnosing kernel issues related to USB hardware.