# ASUS Laptop running Ubuntu 20.10 requires restart after suspending

Tags: boot, usb, suspend, 20.10

After I wake up my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop from suspension by opening its lid, it stays stuck on a black screen with a cursor.

I am unable to interact with anything for a few minutes, until the message `Timeout waiting for response from ISHTP device` appears.  Nothing seems to happen after that, so I just hold down the power button until the laptop restarts.

[It appears](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/hid/intel-ish-hid.txt) that the ISHTP device is some sort of sensor hub for interfacing with USB ports, but I can't figure out much more beyond that.

I've found [this post](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1807406) discussing the problem, but it doesn't appear like anyone has found a solution.   [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1252288/slow-startup-xhci-hcd-00000014-0-timeout-while-waiting-for-setup-device-comm) references a similar problem, but the [other problem it links to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239216/usb-device-descriptor-read-errors-after-upgrade-to-20-04/1239249#1239249) only gives instructions for listing USB ports.

---

Running `lsusb` returns:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:24c5 Elan Microelectronics Corp. Touchscreen
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b59c Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:0a87 Logitech, Inc. G935 Gaming Headset
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The only physical USB I have plugged in right now is Device 002 for my headset.  I am almost positive that it is working as expected, so I don't know what the issue is here.

Any help is much appreciated.

---

Edit: I have 11GiB of RAM and 2GiB of Swap.  Running `free`:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       12146152     6578832     2494308      257020     3073012     5022736
Swap:       2097148        6180     2090968
```

Edit 2: I've upgraded to 20.10, and the issue persists.  I'm going to try upgrading the BIOS when I get the chance.

---

Update: I really don't know what happened, but the issue just... disappeared.  It possibly had something to do with upgrading to 20.10 *and* trying some of thee previous solutions, like running `shutdown`.  Anyway, it's fixed now.

---

Update: The issue is back again.  Still no clue as to what is causing it.

---

Probably final update:  Switching to Fedora fixes the issue, but this obviously doesn't work for most people, so I'm still open to any possible solutions. (updating the BIOS didn't work.)

Comment: How much RAM and Swap do you have? Edit [Edit] your question and show us the output of `free`.

Comment: @waltinator I edited the question - 11GiB of RAM and 2GiB of Swap